# regex to match a string only if a substring is not present

Tags: java, regex

```
str = "sysparm_type=list_data&count=20&start=0&p=incident%3Bq%3Aactive%3Dtrue%5Epriority%3D1%5EEQ&table=incident"
```

I've written a regex for the above string but i want to match it only if the "priority" substring is not present. Here's my regex:

```
.*sysparm_type=list_data&count=(\d+)&start=(\d+)&p=incident.*active.*true^((?!priority).)*$&table=incident
```

But this part  ^((?!priority).)*$ of the regex isn't working.

Comment: Remove `^` and `$` from the tempered greedy token.

Comment: Aren't you better off mapping it as a GET parameter list to an actual request map, then checking if `priority` is present in the keys?

Comment: may I recommend regex101.com as it will allow you to dig into your regex

Comment: Regex is NOT the solution to the universe. Try to use the appropriate tools for your problem (like `split`).

Comment: [Now you have two problems](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems).

Comment: @Tunaki I think regex **is** the solution to the universe, so long as you acknowledge the universe is made of more problems. A "catch 42" if you get me :D

Comment: How strict/literal does your regex need to be?  Can it just check for *anything* that doesn't contain 'priority'?

Comment: @stribizhev your suggestion was bang on... i just removed what you said and it worked like wonders. thanks! man

Comment: You are welcome, still, I can't post it as an answer since a lot of people here think regex is bad for this task. Just delete the question if you can. None of the answers here answer your question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

(a) regexp is bad solution for query string parsing - slow, memory consuming, error prone

(b) try to use any existing library for this task, e.g.  [apache commons](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html):

```
String str = "sysparm_type=list_data&count=20&start=0&p=incident%3Bq%3Aactive%3Dtrue%5Epriority%3D1%5EEQ&table=incident";
List<NameValuePair> pairs = URLEncodedUtils.parse(str, StandardCharsets.UTF8)
for (NameValuePair pair : pairs)
    if (pair.getName().equals("priority"))
        return; // do nothing
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Tarec I've added example snippet

Comment: @ursa I understand your point, but in this case I'm restricted to use a regex only to match. Anyways stribizhev solution did the trick. Thanks all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Caret ^ and $ match at the beginning and end of the entire string. Very greedy.

Wouldn't it be simpler, easier to read and maintain if you just checked for the profile string to be present?

```
    String pattern = "((?!priority).)*";  <== pasted from above, prob not valid regex

  // Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  if (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println("Found value" );

  } else {
     System.out.println("NO MATCH");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check `subString` a simple solution will be checking `str.indexOf(subString)` will return a `int` if it's greater than `0` then `str` contains `subString`.

If you want to do it in regExp use the pattern `.*priority.*`, you can some more restriction of the `substring` if you're sure about its occurrences and position